# Smaller floating windows of smaller sizes

Tags: screen, windows, accessibility, multi-window

I am running Android 12 on a Realme 8 5G phone.

While using Android I was able to create a smaller floating (on top) window, in one of two sizes, for one app (in my case, the WhatsApp app), as shown in the screenshots below (I could not find the screenshots for the even smaller WhatsApp window size). I can drag such Windows by pressing and pulling on the long dash that appears in the title bar of the app.

[image: screen 1]

In general, how do I achieve this with a generic application I want to use in this way, how do I switch between different application sizes for such floating windows, and how many of these can I have at the same time, on my screen?

Thanks.